# Accesing a strict private field using the RTTI

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, rtti

consider this simple code

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Rtti,
  SysUtils;

type
  {$M+}
  TFoo = class
  strict private
    class var Field1 : Integer;
    field2 :  Integer;
  private
    field3 :  Integer;
    class var Field4 : Integer;
  end;


Var
    ctx : TRttiContext;
    f   : TRttiField;
begin
  try
    ctx:=TRttiContext.Create;

    for f in ctx.GetType(TFoo).GetFields do
     Writeln(f.Name);


    Writeln('Done');
    readln;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

When you run this, only the `field3` is listed. it seems which the RTTI does not support fields which are `strict private` or `class var`, So the questions are `Is possible access a strict private field of a delphi class using Rtti or another method?` and I read  the documentation of the [RTTI.TRttiType.GetFields](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TRttiType.GetFields) method  but does mention these restrictions,  `Exist any paper or article which mentions such limitations?`

Comment: There is a problem with your syntax that apparently no one spotted yet: **field2 is a class var too**! See my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't try it right now, but what you seem to need could be `GetDeclaredFields` instead of `GetFields`. This should give **all** (instance) fields of a class but not those of an ancestor class. If you need those too, you'll have to recursively go up the inheritance chain.

As I said, I can't try it right now, so you'll have to see for yourself if it gives you access to strict private fields as well.

### Update

Note that in your declaration of *TFoo*, even you probably didn't intend it, **both Field1 and Field2 are class variables!**.

Just reformat your declaration, and you'll see what I mean:

```
  TFoo = class
  strict private
    class var
      Field1: Integer;
      Field2: Integer;
  private
    // etc...
```

Everything that comes after *class var* is a class variable, until the compiler encounters *var*, *strict*, *private*, *protected*, etc. Try this, and you'll also see *Field2* being written:

```
  TFoo = class
  strict private
    class var 
      Field1: Integer;
    var 
      Field2: Integer;
    // etc...
```

Alternatively try:

```
  TFoo = class
  strict private
    Field2: Integer;
    class var 
      Field1: Integer;
    // etc...
```

This means that **GetFields and GetDeclaredFields don't have any problems with strict private fields**. They just don't return class variables. That makes sense, IMO. Class variables are not members of the object being investigated.

Comment: the `GetDeclaredFields` function return the same result in this case.

Comment: Bummer! It should return more.

Comment: Take a look at the update in my answer. Both *GetFields* and *GetDeclaredFields* work fine, also for *strict private*, but they don't return class variables, since these are, well, not fields of the object.

Comment: +1 for __Note that in your declaration of TFoo, even you probably didn't intend it, both Field1 and Field2 are class variables!.__

Comment: Thanks. just a final question what you mean with `..Class variables are not members of the object being investigated.`?

Comment: @Salvador: Class variables are, well, variables of the class (they only exist once, as part of the class), not fields of an object. So it makes sense they are not listed as fields.

Answer (score 3):

Access to strict private members of a class is possible with [`Class Helpers`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Class_and_Record_Helpers).

See [access-a-strict-protected-property-of-a-delphi-class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330003/access-a-strict-protected-property-of-a-delphi-class/8330615#8330615) for a working example.

Related is also [how-can-access-the-value-of-a-class-var-using-the-address-of-the-class-and-a-offset-to-the-variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554847/how-can-access-the-value-of-a-class-var-using-the-address-of-the-class-and-a-offset-to-the-variable), where class helpers is used to access a strict private class var.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, [`strict private`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Strict_Visibility_Specifiers) is only visible in the scope of the class itself.
They should still be accessible with [Hallvard's hack #5](http://hallvards.blogspot.com/2004/06/hack-5-access-to-private-fields.html), though (except for class fields, I think).

Comment: No need for a hack to access strict private members, use class helpers :)