# How can access the value of a class var using the address of the class and a offset to the variable?

Tags: delphi, pointers, delphi-xe, class-helpers

I Need to access a *strict private class var* value of a class using his instance and a offset to the variable.

so far tried this , check this sample class

```
type
  TFoo=class
   strict private class var Foo: Integer;
   public
   constructor Create;
  end;

constructor TFoo.Create;
begin
  inherited;
  Foo:=666;
end;

//this function works only if I declare the foo var as 
//strict private var Foo: Integer;
function GetFooValue(const AClass: TFoo): Integer;
begin
  Result := PInteger(PByte(AClass) + 4)^
end;
```

As you see the function GetFooValue works only when the foo variable is not declarated like a class var.

The question is how I must modify the  `GetFooValue` in order to get the value of `Foo` when is declarated like `strict private class var Foo: Integer;`

Comment: Just some random guesses: Have you tried this without the `+ 4`? And what happens, if you create an object of type `TFoo` (that is, if you "use the class"), before calling GetFooValue?

Comment: Presumably you don't have the source code available? Is that right?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Yes that is right, I only had the declarations of the class. and the dcu files.

Comment: I can gain access to all strict private members of the target class using a pointer (to the instance) and a offset to the field or property, except the declarated like `class var`.

Comment: If you've got no source then you're out of luck.  Class vars aren't fields, they're global variables, so you can't get at them with field-structure hacks.  This is another reason why you should never use libraries you have no source to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To access a strict private class var, `Class Helper` to rescue.

Example :

```
type
  TFoo = class
  strict private class var
    Foo : Integer;
  end;

  TFooHelper = class helper for TFoo
  private
    function GetFooValue : Integer;
  public
    property FooValue : Integer read GetFooValue;
  end;

function TFooHelper.GetFooValue : Integer;
begin
  Result:= Self.Foo;  // Access the org class with Self
end;

function GetFooValue( F : TFoo) : Integer;
begin
  Result:= F.GetFooValue;
end;

Var f : TFoo;//don't need to instantiate since we only access class methods

begin
  WriteLn(GetFooValue(f));
  ReadLn;
end.
```

Updated example to fit the question.

Comment: I also answered a previous question of yours [accesing-a-strict-private-field-using-the-rtti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525071/accesing-a-strict-private-field-using-the-rtti/8556030#8556030), using class helpers.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't do it that way.  A class var is implemented as a *global variable*, and its memory location doesn't have any predictable relationship to the location of the class VMT (what the class reference points to), which is located in the *constant data* region of your process's memory.

If you need access to this variable from outside the class, declare a `class property` that references it as its backing field.

Comment: This can't help here because Salvador does not have the source.